# Determine whether the api request comes from CURL or POSTMAN?

Tags: java, rest, postman

I want to differentiate the error response of my API endpoint when it hit via browser or via the postman.

I've searched the solution, and a website gives the advice to check HTTP request headers, if it comes from browser then it has `USER-AGENT`

e.g. `USER-AGENT=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36`

That still can be manipulated via postman by setting the USER-AGENT as HTTP header with that value.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Data is sent to the server in 3 ways.

**1. Using `User-Agents`.**

While using CURL, the request has user-agent as `curl/<version>`

While using POSTMAN, the request has

1. user-agent as `PostmanRuntime/<version>`
2. additional header 'Postman-Token' as `<version 4 UUID>` ([Reference](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/launching-postman/settings/#general-settings))

**2. Using Request Params**

Send a token while making requests from webclient.

Eg: `client=webclient`

**3. Using Request Body**

Same as previous, but in request body

**Note :** In all methods, all headers/parameters can be modified.

Answer (score 0):

If the request is from postman then a header will be append in your curl request like **-H 'postman-token: 15f84a34-a7ad-a21a-bb6a-6eb1f304a043'**

This is sample request from postman

```
curl -X GET \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&mine=true' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'postman-token: 15f84a34-a7ad-a21a-bb6a-6eb1f304a043'
```